# Linking angular library project into main project giving errors

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have a library project (say X) that has 2 projects inside it (X-core, X-core-members). I have to use it in another angular project (say ABC).
I have linked it in tsconfig.json and package.json of project ABC.
And on doing npm install in ABC, library dist comes in node_modules.
Then ng serve works fine, but in browser I am getting this error
core.js:6498 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: inject() must be called from an injection context.

I have tried solutions like symlinks:true, etc. but no use. Has it something to do with MatCommonModule?[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the function `inject` is called outside of Angular's context, which in return means that your application has not yet been boostraped, but you're calling one of its functions anyways.

I don't think this is related to your X-ABC link, but rather how you inject the library into the code.

Unfortunately, without any code to help you, or a reproducible example, we w'ont be able to help you anymore than that.

Comment: I have given path in package.json dependency of ABC (both socx - library and ABC are placed inside same folder) - "socx-core": "file:../socx/dist/socx-core",
    "socx-member": "file:../socx/dist/socx-member". And also given path in tsconfig.json

Comment: Even if I am linking both via npm link, still I am getting the same error